# How to get a specific DNS value using PHP?

Tags: php, dns, cname

Here's the URL someone would be visiting:

```
http://dns.example.com/test.php
```

The subdomain `dns.example.com` has a CNAME pointing to `test.testing.org` - so in the browser it still shows `dns.example.com` in the address bar, but they're actually viewing the content of `test.testing.org`.

Is there any way with PHP to get `test.testing.org`? most of the methods I've tried are either showing `dns.example.com` or they're showing the server's hostname - neither of which I want.  I'd also prefer to not have to run a DNS query if possible.

Comment: _"but they're actually viewing the content of test.testing.org"_ No, they're viewing the content of `dns.example.com`. If that happens to be the same content as `test.testing.org`, it's because the web server was configured that way, _not_ the DNS. I.e., using a CNAME to point A to the same ip as B doesn't mean that A will show B's content. What is your use case? I can't envision any situation where you'd need to know this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php

```php
var_dump(
    dns_get_record("dns.example.com", DNS_CNAME)
);
```

Should yield:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["host"]=>
    string(15) "dns.example.com"
    ["class"]=>
    string(2) "IN"
    ["ttl"]=>
    int(3600)
    ["type"]=>
    string(5) "CNAME"
    ["target"]=>
    string(11) "test.testing.org"
  }
}
```

However, where a CNAME is pointing should be completely inconsequential the vast majority of the time, and I have to wonder why you need the information at all.